# Compare a set of numbers in string

Tags: android, string, arraylist, replace, split

I am trying to make somekind of **version checker** for my application.
The idea is to compare the numbers from 2 strings and if 1 set of numbers is bigger then the other a new version has been found.

```
oldString = 360 some - File v1.52.876 [build 2546]
newString = 360 some - File v1.53.421 [build 2687]
```

What I need is to compare the **set numbers after the 'v'** in both strings as there can also be numbers (360) in front of the file, as shown in above example.

Below method checks an **arraylist** (**loadTrackedItems**) which contains the files to be checked agains the **newly received item** (**checkItemTrack**).

But I am having trouble getting the correct numbers.
Is there a better way to do this?, could somebody be so kind and help a bit.

Thank you in advance.

```
public static boolean newTrackedVersion(String checkItemTrack) {
        final List<String> tracking = new ArrayList<String>(loadTrackedItems);
        boolean supported = false;
        for (final String u : tracking) {
            if (checkItemTrack.contains(u)) {
                supported = true;

                // get the index of the last 'v' character
                int trackindex = checkItemTrack.lastIndexOf("v");

                String newItem = checkItemTrack.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "").replace("\\s+", "")
                        .replaceAll("[-\\[\\]^/,'*:.!><~@#$%+=?|\"\\\\()]+", "");
                String inList = u.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "").replace("\\s+", "")
                        .replaceAll("[-\\[\\]^/,'*:.!><~@#$%+=?|\"\\\\()]+", "");

                long newTrack = Long.parseLong(newItem.trim());
                long inTrackList = Long.parseLong(inList.trim());

                if (newTrack > inTrackList) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context,"New version found: " + checkItemTrack, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.w("NEW VERSION ", checkItemTrack);
                    Log.w("OLD VERSION ", u);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return supported;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any exact format of that string?

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly no, the file name could also be (new File v23.1) or new File v2.5.63 or new File v5.12.2 [Build 12]

Comment: try to split the string like String[] separated = string.split(" "); date = separated[0];ist_time = separated[1];  and compare the separated values of two strings ....

Comment: @A.Arjun, not gonna work I am afraid as the string is in no exact format.
There can be multiple spaces in the string not only 2.
Example: newString: this is a very new file v2.63.4 [build 26]
That`s why I need to get the set after the 'v'
Furthetmore there can also be characters like (-,_) in front of the version number which I already took care of replaceAll.

Answer (score 0):

if you receive only two strings to compare this solution will work try it.

```
String oldString = "360 some - File v1.52.876 [build 2546]";
String newString = "360 some - File v1.53.421 [build 2687]";
String oldTemp = oldString.substring(oldString.indexOf('v'), oldString.indexOf('[')).trim();
String newTemp = newString.substring(newString.indexOf('v'), newString.indexOf('[')).trim();
int res = newTemp.compareTo(oldTemp);
if(res == 1){
    //newString is higher
}else if(res == 0){
    //both are same
}else if(res == -1){
    //oldString is higher
}
```

Comment: Thx, this also works when the string has NO build number in it?
Like new file to check v1.23.5
Because that can be the case, my given strings in the questions are only examples of a difficult one.

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=30; regionStart=24; regionLength=-25 on this line:

String newTemp = newString.substring(newString.indexOf('v'), newString.indexOf('[')).trim();

Comment: @Simon if build number is an optional they try this

`String oldTemp = oldString.substring(oldString.indexOf('v'), oldString.indexOf('[') != -1 ? oldString.indexOf('[') : oldString.length()).trim();
    String newTemp = newString.substring(newString.indexOf('v'), newString.indexOf('[') != -1 ? newString.indexOf('[') : newString.length()).trim();`